# Android Intents, onActivityResult, and saving those results to Parse.com

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, parse-platform

I'm trying to capture a photo using the MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent but I'm having some issues with getting it to do what I want. I've got the camera launching, and I can take a picture with it, but I have a few different actions I need to perform depending on what buttons are pushed at what stage.

Basically:

- If on the camera intent and you press the Back button, exit to an activity class
- After taking a picture, if you press Discard, go back to camera intent
- After taking a picture, if you press Save, go back to camera intent

In my activity I've got a method that I call from my onCreate method:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

That seems to be working fine. The issues I'm running into have to do with my onActivityResult method.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap )extras.get("data");
        // Here is where I'm stuck. The docs I've found 
        // are saying this is only a thumbnail.
        // I need to get it as a byte array, I think.
        dispatchTakePictureIntent(); // I'm getting camera intents stacking
                                     // on top of each other from this
                                     // I think there's a way to close them 
                                     // after launching a new one
    }
    // Here is where I think I need to put the if statement 
    // to handle the Discard resultCode
}
// I'm trying to save the photos and upload them to parse
private void savePhoto(byte[] data) {
    parseFile = new ParseFile(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername()
        + System.currentTimeMillis() + .jpg", data);
    // Some other parse methods
    parseFile.saveInBackground(new SaveCallBack() {
        // More parse stuff
    });
}
```

This is my first time ever working with the camera so I've been reading the android docs, but I can't find much that has helped.

Comment: Could help get you started...http://stackoverflow.com/a/23859786/294884